# Do one calculation over the whole list

Tags: list-manipulation, table

I am trying to calculate the numerical residue of the function, but I want to perform it at the whole list and as a return. For example, let's take

```
a = Table[q, {q, 1,5,1}];
b = Table[2 q, {q,0,2,1}];
```

Now, I want to get the residue list, where `a` is some parameter and `b`is the position. For the one value I could do

```
NResidue[a[[1]]/x, {x, b[[1]]}].
```

What I want is a list, that contains

```
Res = {NResidue[a[[1]]/x, {x, b[[1]]}], NResidue[a[[2]]/x, {x, b[[2]]}], ..., 
NResidue[a[[5]]/x, {x, b[[5]]}]};
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Map`? `Table` could also work.

Comment: Make your code more elegant, readable, and efficient:  `a = Range[5]; b = {0,2,4}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Table[q, {q, 1, 5, 1}];

b = Table[2 q, {q, 0, 2, 1}];

Table[Residue[a[[i]] / x, {x, b[[i]]}], {i, Length @ b}]
```

{1, 0, 0}

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

For a result of `Residue[a[[i]]/x, {x, b[[i]]` and and b need to have the same length. Then the command ""MapThread" will do what you want. E.g.:

```
a = Table[q, {q, 1, 3}];
b = Table[2  q, {q, 0, 2}];
MapThread[Residue[#1/x, {x, #2}] &, {a, b}]

{1, 0, 0}
```